# Python: Mapping with Index of Previous Occurrence

Tags: python

I'm often met with an analog of the following problem, and have had trouble writing clean code to solve it. Usually, I have something involving a temporary variable and a for loop, but is there a more elegant way?

Suppose I have a list of booleans or values which evaluate to booleans:

```
[True, False, True, False, False, True]
```

How would I map this to a list of values, with the index of the previous True, inclusive?

```
[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 5]
```

[EDIT] Have tried something along the lines of:

```
def example(lst):
    rst, tmp = [], None
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i]:
            tmp = i
        rst.append(tmp)   
    return rst
```

Assuming the first element of the list is always True.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. When you say map what do you mean? And what do you mean by _the index of the previous True inclusive_?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried (e.g the looping method)

Comment: It returns a list of values, which represent the index of the previous "True" in the original list. In the example, there is one True in the beginning, and then a False. The value of these two elements in the returned list are 0 (0th index in the original list was True).

Comment: And -when the looping method was not what you wanted - why it was not what you wanted?

Comment: What happens when the first element is False?

Comment: Assuming the first element is always True for convenience, added an example of the loop

Answer (score 3):

While it still uses a for loop and a temporary variable, it's still relatively clean, I think. If you want, you could replace the `yield` and append to a list and return that.

```
def get_indexes(booleans):
    previous = 0
    for index, b in enumerate(booleans):
        if b:
            previous = index
        yield previous

>>> b = [True, False, True, False, False, True]
>>> list(get_indexes(b))
[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 5]
```

This is even shorter (although potentially less readable):

```
def get_indexes(booleans):
    previous = 0
    for index, b in enumerate(booleans):
        previous = index if b else previous
        yield previous
```

Comment: If this is what the OP wants I give you a +1, but currently I can't say if it is what he/she wants without he/she giving more info. (btw I'm not the one who gave a -1 to this post)/*edit*/Looking at the edit of the OP's post it is what the OP wants.

Comment: for the second formula you dont need `b == True`, the if statements checks if the condition is true, and `b` automatically is read as `True`

Comment: @Michael0x2a: I think your 2nd answer is a nice example of the Python ternary operation. But you can leave out the True

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
index = 0
bools = [True, False, True, False, False, True]
result = []
for i in range(len(bools)):
    index = i if bools[i] else index
    result.append(index)
```

Not tested, but should work.

Comment: Just ran it. The result was `[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5]`

Comment: Oops, looks like i forgot to update index when needed... working on it

Answer (score 0):

```
[i if b else i-lst[i::-1].index(True) for i,b in enumerate(lst)]
```